# Selected job is not yet complete in Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have written  one Test class in which Test class is working Fine, But Code Coverage is 0% and after running the Test Class i am getting "Selected job is not yet complete in Test Class" .

**Trigger**

```
trigger AssetsAllocation on Assets_Allcoation__c (after insert,after update) {

  List<ID> lid =new List<ID>();
   List<ID> listid=new List<ID>();
    Map<ID, ID> myMap= new Map<ID, Id>();

    List<Assets__c> alloctionlist=new List<Assets__c>();
    List<Employee_Name__c> emplsit=new List<Employee_Name__c>();
    Integer i=0;
    for(Assets_Allcoation__c acc:Trigger.new)
    {
        if(acc.Employee__c!=null){
            myMap.put(acc.Assets__c,acc.Employee__c);
            lid.add(acc.Employee__c);
            listid.add(acc.Assets__c);

        }
    }

  //  emplsit=[Select id,Name,(select id,name from Assets_Allcoations__r)from Employee_Name__c where ID IN:lid];
    Map<ID, Employee_Name__c > emp_map = new Map<ID, Employee_Name__c >([Select id,Name from Employee_Name__c where ID IN:lid]);
    alloctionlist=[Select id,Assigned_To__c from Assets__c where ID IN:listid];
    Id emp_id;
    for(Assets__c asst: alloctionlist){
         emp_id= myMap.get(asst.Id);
         Employee_Name__c emp = emp_map.get(emp_id);
         asst.Assigned_To__c= emp.name;
    }

    update alloctionlist;

}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest

private class TestAssetsAllocationTrigger{

    private static void TestAssetsAllocationTriggerMethod()
    {

            Assets__c a=new Assets__c();
            a.Name='Test';

            insert a;

            Employee_Name__c e=new Employee_Name__c();
            e.Name='Test';

            insert e;

            Map<ID,ID> testmap=new Map<ID,ID>();

            if(e.Name!=null)
            {
                testmap.put(a.id,e.id);

            }


        map<ID,Employee_Name__c> testEmpId=new Map<ID,Employee_Name__c>([Select id,Name from Employee_Name__c where ID =:e.id]);

        id testid=testmap.get(a.id);
        Employee_Name__c testemp=testEmpId.get(testid);
        a.Assigned_To__c=testemp.Name;

        update a;

   }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think that this test class would test the assets_allcoation__c trigger? It doesn't insert or update an assets_allcoation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your method signature as such:

```
private static testmethod void TestAssetsAllocationTriggerMethod()
    {
```

or

```
@isTest
private static void TestAssetsAllocationTriggerMethod()
    {
```

If that does not work then  I do not think it is something wrong with your code. You may wish to open a support case.

And your class is unnecessarily long, here is a shortened version:

```
private static testmethod void TestAssetsAllocationTriggerMethod()
    {

            Assets__c a=new Assets__c(
                    Name='Test'
                );

            insert a;

            Employee_Name__c e=new Employee_Name__c(
                    Name='Test'
                );


            insert e;

            system.assertNotEquals(null,e.id,'Employee_Name__c was not inserted');


        a.Assigned_To__c = e.name;

        update a;

   }
```

And as you seen once it is shortened, it does not make sense what you are actually testing....You are not even inserting an Assets_Allcoation__c so I do not think it will be covered unless there are other triggers creating the records.

Comment: I want a Support Case Because it is not working

Comment: Then submit one....